# Flutter Google Sign In Issue (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, e5.b: 10:, null, null)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

This is the error message that i am getting, whenever i try to use google sign in (This issue doesn't happen in debug, release and profile versions of the app. It only happens at the version (aab) that i upload to the google playstore):

PlatformException(sign_in_failed, e5.b: 10:, null, null)

Here is everything google related in my pubspec.yaml file:

```
 google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0
 google_sign_in: ^6.1.1
 google_sign_in_dartio: ^0.2.2+1
 googleapis: ^10.1.0
 firebase_core: ^2.13.0
 firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
```

These are the codes that i use to implement google sign in to my app:

```
API CALL:

class ThirdPartyService extends AppService {
  static ThirdPartyService get instance => ThirdPartyService();

  ThirdPartyService() : super(path: '');

  static final googleSignInInstance = GoogleSignIn(
    serverClientId:
        'MY_CLIENT_ID',
  );

  Future signInWithGoogle() async {
    final gUser = googleSignInInstance.currentUser ?? await googleSignInInstance.signIn();
    if (gUser != null) {
      final gAuthEmail = gUser.email;
      final token = (await gUser.authentication).accessToken;
      var response = await post('/OAUTH/GOOGLE', {
        "EMAIL_ADDRESS": gAuthEmail,
        "TOKEN": token,
      });
      if (!response.success) throw response.message;
      return AppData.userDetail.value = {...response.data};
    }
    throw 'GoogleSignInFailed';
  }
}

------------------

GOOGLE SIGN IN FUNCTION:

void loginWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      await ThirdPartyService.instance.signInWithGoogle();
      Get.offAll(
        () => RateAppInitWidget(
          builder: (rateMyApp) => BottomNavBar(rateMyApp: rateMyApp),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
        'Warning',
        'Google Sign in failed. Try again later.',
        colorText: AppColors.black,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      );
    }
  }
```

How can i fix this issue? Please help

P.S: My app is approved and verified by google and i've tried many solutions related to SHA1 keys.

Hello, I've followed every step of implementing google sign in to my app (firebase steps, google consoles, in app configurations etc etc). Even though the google sign in is working correctly in debug, release and profile versions. It doesn't work when i upload the aab to the google playstore. I've searched through many solutions and literally tried most if not every fix that i could find but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the different SHA-1 keys for production and to be able to do that you should read this article

https://medium.com/@hamza.azee91/google-sign-in-into-your-android-app-step-by-step-57550e6e9398

You'll see the guide on how to do the google cloud API console and also on the firebase console.

Comment: The thing is, I've already done all of this. I've tried both the debug and release SHA1 keys and it is working properly on degub, release and profile versions. However the issue still persists on the aab that i released on google playstore.

Comment: Did you add the different keys to your playstore too and your firebase?

Comment: Yes, I have added the different keys to both the firebase and the google cloud console

Comment: That is very weird.

Comment: I've just checked google play console and noticed I haven't used the signing key anywhere. Now i added it to firebase and cloud console created a new client id for me to use. I will be giving it a try now, wish me luck!

Comment: Update: Now there are 3 Sha1 and 3 sha256 keys on firebase, after i added the signing ones that i get from google play console as well. I used the most recent client id that was automatically created. However after adding the new google_sercives.json to the project and running flutter clean and flutter run i've got this error:

PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)


I tested in profile mode too...

Comment: I have 5 OAuth 2.0 client Ids in google cloud console. Only the latest 'Web client (auto created by Google Service)' one works properly and that was created back on Sep 16 and it was the same one it was both working in debud,release and profile mods but not working on the aab release of the app. Am i supposed to keep using that 'WEB' one even after adding the signing keys from the google play console to firebase?

Comment: Could this be related to the an outdated 'firebase_options.dart' file in my project?


static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(

    apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',

    appId: 'MY_APP_ID',

    messagingSenderId: 'MY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID',

    projectId: 'MY_PROJECT_ID',

    storageBucket: 'MY_PROJECT_STORAGE_BUCKET',

  );

perhaps i am missing some options here and i need to add them?

Comment: At this point I think anything can be a solution, but i'd strongly suggest taking a few steps back to visit how you created your SHA-1 keys.
Redo even getting the google-services.json because as you add a new key, you have to download the new json.

Answer (score 0):

I am Facing the same issue tried everything mentioned above. Still the issue is not getting fixed the weird thing is the **google sign** in is working flawlessly on **IOS** Devices the issue im only facing is on **ANDROID** devices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).